# How we draw resizable and dragable textarea on google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We can draw Polygon, Circle, Rectangle and Line on google map api. But if we want to draw dragable and re-sizable textarea on google maps api then how we achieve that?

I know this may be possible by 'Custom Overlay', But i don't know how.

Comment: Does it need to be positionned on the map at certain coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

:) This is what you want... try this

> https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/